invalid BigNumber string
Say I wanted to create a slightly modified ERC-721, which tracked its historical metadata states. Something like so:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.26;

import { ERC721 } from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

event MetadataUpdate(uint256 tokenId);

contract ERC721Experiment is ERC721, Ownable {

// Constructor will be called on contract creation

mapping(uint256 tokenId => string uri) tokenURIs;
mapping(uint256 tokenId => string[] uriHistory) pastTokenURIs;

constructor() ERC721("ERC721Experiment", "E721E") Ownable(msg.sender) {}

// Allows minting of a new NFT 
function mintCollectionNFT(address collector, uint256 tokenId) public onlyOwner() {
    _safeMint(collector, tokenId); 
}

function tokenURI(uint256 _tokenId) public override view returns (string memory) {
    return tokenURIs[_tokenId];
}

function uriHistory(uint256 _tokenId) public view returns (string[] memory) {
    return pastTokenURIs[_tokenId];
}

function setTokenUri(uint256 _tokenId, string calldata uri) public onlyOwner() {
    pastTokenURIs[_tokenId].push(tokenURIs[_tokenId]);
    tokenURIs[_tokenId] = uri;
    emit MetadataUpdate(_tokenId);
}

}
This contract compiles fine. And I can mint specific tokens with mintCollectionNFT. Great!
However, when I attempt to call setTokenUri with a test url (www.google.com (or indeed any other non numeric string)), I get the following error message:
invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="www.google.com", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)

Weirdly, calling setTokenUri with a number (e.g. 1), succesfully runs the function. For the life of me I can't understand what I've messed up here. Any pointers would be super welcome.
Thank you

What are the exact two arguments that you’re passing while calling the setTokenUri function?
